# display both dollar sign and two decimals

Tags: c#, currency

i haved looked all over the place! I swear! im trying to get my output to display both the "$" and two decimals to the right of the period. Im using C#

```
//declare variable
                decimal decInputDays;
                decimal decInputAmountofBooks;
                decimal decOutputAmountofFine;

                decimal FINE_CALCULATE = .05m;

                //get values from the form
                decInputDays = decimal.Parse(txtDays.Text);
                decInputAmountofBooks = decimal.Parse(txtBooks.Text);


                //determine fine amount
                decOutputAmountofFine = decInputDays * decInputAmountofBooks * FINE_CALCULATE;
                //display fine amount

                lblAmount.Text = decOutputAmountofFine.ToString("c");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
decimalVal.ToString("C2")
```

Comment: tried that.... still nothing my last line is                                                                                        lblAmount.Text = decOutputAmountofFine.ToString("C2");                                           and it didnt change anything in the display

Answer (score 0):

The exact output format will depend on the current Culture selection on the computer it's being run on, but `ToString("C")` should produce output with currency symbol, thousands separators where required, plus two decimals following.  You can specify a number if you need more or fewer decimal digits, but the default of 2 digits is the most common.

If all else fails you should be able to force the format like this:

```
lblAmount.Text = string.Format("${0:#,0.00}", decOutputAmountofFine);
```

Or if you're using C# version 6 (VS2015):

```
lblAmount.Text = $"${decOutputAmountofFine:#,0.00}";
```

Note that `#,` is the "insert thousands separator" specifier and can still be affected by localization... but I don't know of any locales that use any value other than 3 for separator distance (`System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyGroupSizes`).  Check the values in `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat` to see what is configured for your location.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what your current result is.  But whatever it is, it sounds like your problem is culture-related.

Consider forcing the culture to `en-US`.  It should give you the currency format you are looking for:

```
decOutputAmountofFine.ToString("c", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```